# Имя "pylint" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы

Tags: python

Установил pylint через pip, в pip list отображается `pylint            2.4.4`
при запуске `pylint` дает ошибку 
`pylint : Имя "pylint" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторит
е попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ pylint
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pylint:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

win 10

Comment: 1) Нужно запускать в консоли/терминале, например в `cmd` 2) Папка с `pylint` должна быть доступна в переменной окружения `PATH` либо нужно запускать из папки с `pylint` 3) Скорее всего можно через питон запустить его, если тот является питоничьим файлом 4) А то что у вас вывелось, это похоже на ошибку `PowerShell`